# Execute all sql queries in migration yii2

Tags: php, sql, mysql, yii2

I'm trying to make a migration that executes many queries at once on different tables

```
$sql = '';

$sql .= "UPDATE card_series SET Code = 903 WHERE ID = 1600;";

$cardsSeries1600 = CardList::find()
            ->where(['seriesId' => 1600])
            ->orderBy('ID');
        $cardNum = 2;
        foreach ($cardsSeries1600->each() as $card) {
               if ($card->client_id != NULL) {
                    $sql .= "DELETE FROM client_cards WHERE card_id = ".$card->ID.";";
                }
            $number = str_pad($cardNum, 8, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
            $cardId = (1903).$number; 
            $sql .= "UPDATE card_list SET ID = '".$cardId."', Code = 903, Number = '".$number."' WHERE ID = ".$card->ID.";";

            $sql .= "UPDATE card_list_log SET card_id = '".$cardId."', Code = 903, Number = '".$number."' WHERE card_id = ".$card->ID.";";

            $cardNum++;
}

\Yii::$app->db->createCommand($sql)->execute();
```

But in the end, I only have one first request `UPDATE card_series SET Code = 903 WHERE ID = 1600;`

I tried to dump the `$sql` variable, and all requests are there, but only the first one is still executed

How can I make it so that all my requests are executed one by one??

Comment: Can you see, https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/3744

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try like below.

```
public function safeUp()
{
    $query = "your query statement";
    $this->execute($query);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it helped, but now I'm facing another problem, described in more detail in a new post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76287963/yii2-sql-migration-overwrite-newly-changed-records