# yii2 sql migration overwrite newly changed records

Tags: php, sql, mysql, yii2

I'm trying to create a migration that changes the records I need in a table

```
$sql = '';

$sql .= "UPDATE card_series SET Code = 903 WHERE ID = 1600;";

$cardsSeries1600 = CardList::find()
            ->where(['seriesId' => 1600])
            ->orderBy('ID')
            ->all();
        $cardNum = 2;

        foreach ($cardsSeries1600 as $card) {
                $number = str_pad($cardNum, 8, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
                $cardId = (1903).$number; 
                $sql .= "UPDATE card_list SET ID = ".$cardId.", Code = '903', Number = '".$number."' WHERE ID = ".$card->ID.";";

                $cardNum++;
        }
        $this->execute($sql);
```

But in the end, my migration works in such a way that at first all my necessary records change, but then immediately they change to even newer ones, here is an example

> UPDATE card_series SET Code = 903 WHERE ID = 1600;UPDATE card_list SET ID = 190300000002, Code = '903', Number = '00000002' WHERE ID = 1111000005;UPDATE card_list SET ID = 190300000003, Code = '903', Number = '00000003' WHERE ID = 1111000011;UPDATE card_list SET ID = 190300000004, Code = '903', Number = '00000004' WHERE ID = 190300000002;UPDATE card_list SET ID = 190300000005, Code = '903', Number = '00000005' WHERE ID = 190300000003;

How can this be fixed?

Comment: You used =>1600 where you wanted to use just =1600

Comment: @Grumpy sorry, I don't quite understand what you mean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can try like below ?

```
    $sql = '';
$sql .= "UPDATE card_series SET Code = 903 WHERE ID = 1600;";
$this->execute($sql);
$cardsSeries1600 = CardList::find()->where(['seriesId' => 1600])->orderBy('ID')
    ->all();
$cardNum = 2;
$sql = '';
foreach ($cardsSeries1600 as $card) {
        $number = str_pad($cardNum, 8, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
        $cardId = (1903).$number; 
        $sql .= "UPDATE card_list SET ID = ".$cardId.", Code = '903', Number = '".$number."' WHERE ID = ".$card->ID.";";
        $cardNum++;
}
$this->execute($sql);
```